# LibreOffice command line font substitution at pptx to pdf conversion

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, fonts, pdf

**Question**

Is there any way to specify to `libreoffice`, via commandline, to use `Cambria` for occurences of `Calibri` in the PDF generation without the need of any user-interaction?

**Context**

I am using this command:

```
libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf --outdir images/output/ images/Mockups.pptx
```

or this one:

```
unoconv -f pdf -o images/output/ images/Mockups.pptx
```

to automatically convert a `PPTX` to `PDF` in a `virtualbox` machine launched with `vagrant` running `ubuntu/trusty64`.

Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
[...]
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y unoconv imagemagick default-jdk ant docbook-xsl fop libxml2-utils xsltproc php5-cli
SHELL
```

The original `pptx` is edited by people using windows and uses the `Calibri` font. I can't require them to use different settings or fonts.

As the `Calibri` font is not in the `trusty` distribution, the `PDF` conversion done by the `libreoffice` messes the layout.

I've read `Cambria` is metric-equivalent to `Calibri`.

So, as stated, the question is how to instruct `libreoffice` for a certain font substitution via command line.

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548755/powerpoint-ppt-to-jpg-or-png-image-conversion-using-php - This is what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: A quick and dirty solution would be to create symbolic links from the Calibri font files to the corresponding Cambria files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pptx` file format is just a zip file with a different extension, you could try unzipping it and doing a text substitution:

```
unzip -d tmp Mockups.pptx
find tmp -type f | xargs sed -i 's/Calibri/Cambria/g'
( cd tmp; zip -r ../Mockups2.pptx . )
rm -Rf tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Didn't know it's a ZIP. This Works! Nevertheless, the sed must have a `/g` to process several occurences of the happening within the same file. Finally mention that the `zip` seems not to support compressing a dir stripping the first path element, so we need to `cd` into it necessarily. I'm going to edit the answer with the script that works.

Comment: @XaviMontero: Please feel free to edit my script, we don't really need my half-baked version, and the edits are versioned anyway.

Comment: Edited. Submitted for peer-review.

Comment: @XaviMontero: Reviewers were too eager... I edited it myself.

Answer (score 4):

We had a similar issue with LibreOffice under Alfresco (which also runs headless).  Installing the ChromeOS fonts packages for Carlito (Calibri equivalent) and Caladea (Cambria equivalent) fixed it, using a hint from here: https://wiki.debian.org/SubstitutingCalibriAndCambriaFonts.  Changing the mappings within LO did nothing, neither on the headless nor on the desktop - only installing the packages solved it. (For completeness, we had added the entries for the mappings to the LO registrymodifications.xcu and that achieved nothing, on either platform - editing the files under conf.d takes precedence, it seems).

Packages installed were:

Note: $ below is the system prompt...

Linux:

> $ sudo apt-get install fonts-crosextra-carlito fonts-crosextra-caladea

FreeBSD: (Hint:do the search first as name may change over time)

> $ pkg search cros
>
> $ sudo pkg install crosextrafonts-caladea-20130214_1
> crosextrafonts-carlito-20130920_2

You may need to run:

> $ fc-cache -r

Check with:

> $ fc-match Calibri
>
> Carlito-Regular.ttf: "Carlito" "Regular"
>
> $ fc-match Cambria
>
> Caladea-Regular.ttf: "Caladea" "Regular"

Works perfectly now.

These installs create the following files which give the desired font substitutions (depending on your platform):

Linux (Ubuntu 14.x):

> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/30-0-google-crosextra-caladea-fontconfig.conf
>
> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/30-0-google-crosextra-carlito-fontconfig.conf

These are linked from /etc/fonts/conf.d like so:

> 30-0-google-crosextra-caladea-fontconfig.conf ->
> ../conf.avail/30-0-google-crosextra-caladea-fontconfig.conf
>
> 30-0-google-crosextra-carlito-fontconfig.conf ->
> ../conf.avail/30-0-google-crosextra-carlito-fontconfig.conf

FreeBSD (10.x):

> /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.avail/30-metric-aliases.conf

...linked ala...

> /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf@ ->
> /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.avail/30-metric-aliases.conf